# Does Facebook use long polling for chat and notifications?

Tags: ajax, facebook, comet

or anything else ?

Comment: Can you expand and clarify your question?

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at firebug suggests and verifies that yes, they do in fact use long polling.

Comment: Because I can see them issuing requests that take time to respond, and when they do respond, they immediately issue a new request.  Smells like long polling.